# Not able to generate allure-report in allure-testng-maven project

Tags: allure

I'm not able to generate allure-report in allure-testng-maven project .Even i use *site* command in maven it's only generating site folder not allure-report folder which contain xml file.

Error which i'm getting in eclipse is [image]

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>



  <name>xyz</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


<!-- Define constant value -->
  <properties>   
    <allure.version>1.5.2</allure.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version> 
    <jdk.version>1.8.0_121</jdk.version>  
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding> 
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <!-- <suiteXmlFile>src/test/java/Lineup/testng_Lineup.xml</suiteXmlFile> -->
  </properties>


  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
        <artifactId>saxon-dom</artifactId>
        <version>8.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jexcelapi/jxl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->


    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <version>6.10</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For ReportNG results -->
<!--    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
        <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            </exclusion>

        </exclusions>
    </dependency> -->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bitbucket.cowwoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>diff-match-patch</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.java-diff-utils</groupId>
        <artifactId>diffutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
    </dependency>


 <build>
        <finalName>mswautomation</finalName>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.10.v20150310</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/allure-maven-plugin</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>1234</stopPort>
                    <httpConnector>
                        <!--host>localhost</host -->
                        <port>8080</port>
                    </httpConnector>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </build>



  <reporting>
    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: Use Allure 2 instead. Check out the example project here https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-testng-example

Comment: (Not related to your problem) PDFBox is at 2.0.6 now.

Comment: @DmitryBaev don't know how to connect with you. Have a question about Allure. Can the report be saved as PDF? Or any other format to be mailed? And why the report is Ok when it generated on a web server, but when I open index.html data about tests is empty?

Comment: you can use our Gitter https://gitter.im/allure-framework/allure-core for such type of questions